# How to close a dialog opened by my own application

Tags: vb6, dialog

I have a VB6 application that needs to respond to an update call by closing itself automatically. No user interaction should be necessary to close the application. This all works fine except when a system dialog has been opened. This dialog can be used for opening files or setting printer properties. Something like this:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tweakers.net](http://tweakers.net/ext/f/Kjz0R5IvkCNfXRRefrqHFmFc/full.png))</sub>

The "Print Setup" window would still close gracefully, but the properties dialog is a system dialog that won't close when my program closes. Result is that the application won't close but remains (invisibly) active. I have to use the task manager to force close it.

Open forms can be detected with a code like this:

```
For Each Form In Forms
    ...
Next Form
```

These dialogs do not appear in this array of opened forms. Is there a way to detect all system dialogs that are opened by my application and close them in an orderly way?

Comment: try using unloadMe to hide currently open form and to show other form use LoadFormName.

Comment: @coder closing forms is not the problem. The system dialogs are. They cannot be closed in the way you close a normal form. You can also not simply detect them.

Comment: Why do you need to close your application without user interaction - this is non standard to say the least. What happens if the print dialog is not shown (i.e. I am using the application) and an update call comes in? The application just disappears in front of your eyes?

Comment: Is that question really relevant? I need to close it because i can. Is this a discussion board about what's good user interaction or can we just discuss code? And don't talk about something non standard because, as a developer, nothing is standard. If everything was standard we don't need developers do we?

Answer (score 1):

I don't have time to devise a full answer but here are some hints.

One solution [might](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/178893) be to

1. Iterate through all the top-level windows belonging to your VB6 program
2. Find the hWnd for each one
3. Use PostMessage to send [WM_CLOSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632617%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to each one.

Karl Peterson has an [article](http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2009/11/16/no-such-thing-as-a-windowless-vb-app.aspx?m=1)  with code that iterates through all the windows belonging to the current thread and determines their hWnd.

Bring your hatchet! :)

Comment: I was already looking for solutions that depend on Hwnd and parent windows and stuff. I didn't see this option before. I'll give it a try and report back later.

Comment: Great. If you come up with a decent solution, do post it back as an answer.

Comment: I tried the EnumThreadWindows function but i did not get the expected result. I continued with my own lead and that seems to work. But i still hope there is a better solution.

Comment: Out of curiosity: what exactly happened with EnumThreadWindows?

Comment: EnumThreadWindows did not list the windows i had open. Instead it more looked like it listed objects placed on the form. I could not detect any system dialog or application form being detected with this function. If you have other experiences with it then i would like to see some small code that does it.

Answer (score 1):

Semi-answering my own question. I'm still looking for better solutions, but this has done the trick so far.

I use `EnumWindows` together with `IsWindowVisible` to get the Hwnd for **all** visible windows. Then I use `GetAncestor` to get the Hwnd from the ancestor form (the opening form). I check if that ancestor Hwnd belongs to my own application by looping through all forms. If it belongs to my application i close the window with a WM_CLOSE by `PostMessage`.

This is probably not the best solutions since i need to walk through all opened windows from all running applications. If somebody has a better solutions then I like to hear it. Something that simply gives me the Hwnd of opened windows for my own application would probably speed things up.

Answer (score 1):

As a huge hack, you could try calling `Sendkeys "{esc}"` until your form gets the keypress event.

Answer (score 1):

Another opiton is just to hold off the shutdown until the dialogs are closed (you know when you show it and when it returns so a simple flag will do).

Comment: The whole trick is that -when an update is issued- users have a couple of minutes to close the application themselves. If that not happens because they are not sitting behind theire computer the application needs to shutdown automatically. Dialogs can still be open so i need to handle them.